# access web server on private network

Tags: networking, iptables, routing, linux-networking

I would like to access a web server(10.0.0.3) on private network via other machine, that has connection to the private network(10.0.0.2) and has a public ip too(23.88.XXX.XXX).
I am trying with this, but it is not working yet:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -d 23.88.XXX.XXX --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 10.0.0.3:80
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Can anybody help me, what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to access service over lan or wan? Is webserver running on 10.0.0.3? Maybe you can turn firewall off for testing and check again.

Comment: I am trying to access the service over wan from my home computer. The server is running on 10.0.0.3 and as far as I know, there is no firewall none of them, they are newly installed debian computers.

Comment: Can you access web server from lan ? http://10.0.0.3

Comment: Yes, I can ping it.

Comment: If you open browser on 10.0.0.2 and go to http ://10.0.0.3 do you see webpage?

Comment: I can't try it, because this private network is in a cloud. I can just ssh into 23.88.XXX.XXX, and I can ssh from 23.88.XXX.XXX to 10.0.0.3. I've installed apache on the web-server, before I removed the public IP of it.

Comment: Ssh to 10.0.0.2 and run command "curl 10.0.0.3" without quotation marks. Do you see any html output?

Comment: Yes, I see the HTML output of the apache server.

Comment: What cloud provider are you using?

Comment: I use hetzner cloud

Comment: Have you enabled IP packet formwarding on `10.0.0.2`?

Comment: Yes, I enabled ip4 forwarding on 10. 0.0.2